# jsf Issues with buttons-allign

Tags: jsf

I have form with login-button in center of form:

```
<h:panelGrid  columns="3" >
.....
<td align="center">
<a:commandButton id="loginButton">
<td>
.....
</h:panelGrid>
```

I want added save-button, so that the two buttons are in the center. But if just add button to the `<td>`, the save-button is set on right.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't use `<td>` with `<panelGrid>`. Read this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf.

Answer (score 0):

jsf Issues with buttons-allign

```
 <h:commandButton id="SaveButton" value="Save" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" action="save"/>

**or use div tag**

<div style="margin-left:200px;">
      <h:commandButton id="SaveButton" value="Save" action="save"/>
</div>
```